# I found a car comparison with the following:

Tags: power

car1                         car2                         car3

Displacement (cc) 
1591                         1197                         1497

Fuel Type
Petrol                       Petrol                        Petrol

Max Power (bhp@rpm) 
122 bhp @ 6400 rpm          83 bhp @ 6000 rpm             121 bhp @ 6500 rpm

Max Torque (Nm@rpm) 
154 Nm @ 4850 rpm           115 Nm @ 4000 rpm                  150 Nm @ 4500 rpm

Mileage (ARAI) (kmpl) 
15.29                        21.4                              17

Which car has maximum power?
How do I calculate the same?

I calculated the power for the 1st car = 154*4850/5252=142

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot or at least should not calculate the power like that. The manufacturers engine power figures are from testing the engines on a dynamometer and measuring the values produced, they also take into account temperature, humidity and many other factors, so that there is some comparability between the results posted.

Answer (score 1):

The car rated with the maximum power figure based on the manufacturers numbers you've quoted is car 1 which has 122bhp.

Is there a reason behind the question you are asking other than which car has the highest maximum power figure?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct. Just note that the maximum torque and maximum horsepower don't necessarily happen at the same RPM. Even if torque is lower at 6500RPM than at 4800RPM, the RPM is so much higher that you're doing more "work" at 6500RPM.